# Laravel 5 - relationships between models

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have a database structure as follows.

```
campaign

id    | name         | ...
----------------------
5     | something    | ...
----------------------

campaign_creatives

id    | type         | campaignId
---------------------------------
1     | something    | 5
---------------------------------

campaign_creatives_data

id | name       | campaignCreativesId
--------------------------------------------
1  | something  | 1
--------------------------------------------
2  | something  | 1
--------------------------------------------
3  | something  | 1
--------------------------------------------
```

Within my Campaign Model, I have

```
public function campaignCreatives()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\CampaignCreatives', 'campaignId');
}
```

Within CampaignCreatives I have

```
public function campaign()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Campaign');
}

public function campaignCreativesData()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\CampaignCreativesData', 'campaignCreativesId');
}
```

And within CampaignCreativesData

```
public function campaignCreatives()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\CampaignCreatives');
}
```

The theory behind this is a Campaign can have One CampaignCreatives.  A CampaignCreatives can have one or more CampaignCreativesData.

I am not too sure if my Models are correct for this?  I have a feeling it is not.  Reason I say this is that within one of my views, if I do

```
{{ dd($campaignCreative) }}
```

I can see the information relating to the campaignCreative.  However, if I do

```
{{ dd($campaignCreative->campaignCreativesData) }}
```

I get the warning

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$campaignCreativesData
```

Are my relationships set up appropriately, or am I doing something wrong with the foreign keys?

Thanks

Comment: It seems that your `$campaignCreative` is a Collection, not a single object. What is the output of your `dd($campaignCreative)`?

Comment: oh, if I get it as a single Object instead, then I can access the data :-)

Answer (score 1):

you need to loop through that collection

```
@foreach ($campaignCreative->campaignCreativesData as $campaignCreativesData)
{{ $campaignCreativesData->name }}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
{{ dd($campaignCreative->campaignCreativesData()) }}
```

Comment: It says Method campaignCreativesData does not exist